# Returning php variable from jQuery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Im sure this is a simple solution, however I have had no success in my attempts as my jQuery & ajax is not the greatest. I am making an ajax call to my php script which is doing error checking for a form. If there are errors, I am showing a hidden div and displaying the error messages no problem. However if there are no error messages, I would like an alert to appear. The issue is the alert does not display when there are no errors

Javacript

```
        $.ajax({
         url: '../assets/inc/process.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: formData, 
         dataType: 'html'
            })
            .always(function(data){
                if (data == 'success'){
                    alert('it worked!');
                }
                else{
                    $('#responsediv').show();
                    $('#responsediv').html(data);
                }
             });
        });
```

I have also tried

```
          if (data.success == 'success'){
                alert('it worked!');
            }
            else{
                $('#responsediv').show();
                $('#responsediv').html(data);
            }
```

PHP

```
  if ($result_new_row){
        $success = 'success';
        echo $success;
  }
```

I know for sure that the new row is being inserted as I can see it in the database.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data back from PHP as an array (PS data type should be json)

PHP

```
 if ($result_new_row){
        $return['result'] = 'success';
        //comment this out when you are positive it's working
        echo "hello";
  } else {
        $return['result'] = 'error';
  }
  print(json_encode( $return);
```

jQuery

```
    $.ajax({
     url: '../assets/inc/process.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: formData, 
     dataType: 'json'
        })
        .always(function(data){
            if (data.result == 'success'){
                alert('it worked!');
            } else {
                $('#responsediv').show();
                $('#responsediv').html(data);
            }
         });
    });
```

If this isn't returning correctly make sure your PHP function is actually working right first.

If you use Chrome you can see your AJAX calls by bringing up the inspector and changing to the network tab, then clicking XHR will show you each AJAX request, what is being sent and the response.